# Different metric score when using CatBoost Regression with CPU and GPU with the same random_seed

Tags: python, gpu, cpu, catboost

Running the same code using CPU and GPU gives me different RMSE score. Why?

I was running the following code over and over, while doing tweaks in the feature engineering and feature selection stage.

```
from catboost import CatBoostRegressor

model = CatBoostRegressor(iterations=1000, learning_rate=0.05, depth=5, random_seed=69);

df_ser_full.Model.fit(
    X_train,
    y_train, 
    use_best_model=True,
    eval_set=(X_test, y_test),
    plot=True,
    silent=True
    );
```

After a while, I got tired of waiting for the training, so I switched over to train on GPU instead of CPU by replacing the second line of code with the following

```
model = CatBoostRegressor(iterations=1000, learning_rate=0.05, depth=5, task_type='GPU', random_seed=69);
```

The training now sped up by about 5 times, but I noticed that the metric dropped significantly (the RMSE from the test set went from 0.13955@CPU to 0.14377@GPU). Are the GPU and CPU using different Random Number Generators through with the same interface, or is there something else that I am missing?

I am using the following hardware

- Intel Core i9-8950HK (CPU @ 2.90GHz)
- NVIDIA Quadro P2000

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that could affect the results:

1. The default value of border_count parameter is 255 by default for CPU and 127 for GPU

So try setting it to 255, and please write here if it has helped.

2. GPU training is not deterministic, because it uses atomic additions of derivatives. So every time you will get a slightly different result for your GPU training. This should not have a large effect on quality though.

Comment: Hi Anna, I tried setting border_count of GPU mode to match that of CPU mode. (254 is the default for CPU.) But the metrics from GPU are still worse.